# Zip using C# of same file produces output zip of different size on server and windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, zip

There is one dll and if we zip it on windows 10 and windows server 2012 using same code, it produces different size. Size difference is exactly 5 bytes. C# code is

```
private static void Zip()
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\USB\adammigrate.dll");
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(@"C:\USB\adammigrate.dll", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            using (var zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(@"C:\USB\adammigrate1.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("adammigrate.dll", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
                entry.LastWriteTime = fileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToUniversalTime();
                using (Stream stream2 = entry.Open())
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                    int numBytesRead;
                    while ((numBytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        stream2.Write(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Size on disk is same but actual size is differ by 5 bytes. PFA Zip Info for both the zip files. [image][image]

Comment: Are both servers 64bit?

Comment: Are both has same file system NTFS?

Comment: the size on disk is a feature of the file system, not the actual file payload / contents; and even if the file bytes were different sizes: zip is not a "there's only one possible way to represent this data" format - the exact same content can take different output sizes depending on choices made in the implementation

Comment: yes both systems are 64 bit and NTFS.

Comment: @Marc: I agree size on disk is a feature of file system. My Question why same code zipping same dll on different Windows operating system producing different sizes and how I can avoid that ?

Comment: @mohitgarg in that case, see the answer I wrote and deleted earlier (now undeleted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zip format is not guaranteed to have a single representation; it *can be* different sizes depending on specifics of the implementation (i.e. multiple encoding options are available, and it may or may not choose the absolute best one). The only important question is: does it unzip back to the original content? If it fails to unzip, *then* it is interesting. But being different sizes by itself doesn't mean anything.

If you want an absolute guarantee of getting the exact same zip output, you'll have to find an implementation that offers output stability as a documented feature; the implementation you're using clearly doesn't offer that. *Usually* tools like zip want to retain the ability to quietly improve their choices for your benefit between versions (and sometimes it might *try* to make things better generally, with the side-effect that sometimes it makes it worse).

If you were anticipating always getting the exact same bytes back: then zip is probably not an appropriate file format for you, unless you only compare the sizes and contents of the *internal* payloads (i.e. what they would be once decompressed), not the zip file itself.